# How to prevent multiple event calling with jQuery on("change")

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

I was having duplicates events with this code that was purposely supposed to run multiples times:

```js
$('selector').on('change', myFunction);
```

Then I did some Googling and I saw that I could/should do

```js
$('selector').off('change', myFunction).on('change', myFunction);
```

to unbind it first, which makes sense, but I still had the same issue ending up with multiples bindings.

Then curiously I changed my code to include a **()** after my function's name on the `off()` part and it worked!

```js
$('selector').off('change', myFunction()).on('change', myFunction);
```

So, my question is: am I doing right by using `myFunction()` instead of `myFunction` on the `off()` part?

Comment: I mean, the code is working fine now, as it's supposed. But why do I need to include **()** on the `off` and not on the `on`?

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/off/

There is no `off` overload that accepts the set of parameters you are calling it with. Your "working" code does the same as

```
$('selector').off('change').on('change', myFunction);
```

with unwanted side-effect of executing `myFunction` in `.off('change', myFunction())`.

Comment: This can be changed to `$('selector').off('change.myFn').on('change.myFn', myFunction);` so other on change handlers don't get cancelled.

Comment: @Sagar correct. More on qualifying events with "event namespaces" - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Igor, thanks! I understood. The odd is that even doing the `off` with "event namespaces" I still get multiples bindings... I'll check if I doing something else in somewhere else.

Comment: @RafaelTrevisan - show how you do it - you can add new version of your code to the question, preserving the original, of course

Answer (score 0):

Just delegate the event once on page load and don't add multiple listeners

```
$(document).on('change','selector', myFunction);
```

I used `document` but you can move that to a closer permanant asset in the page that is an ancestor of the element(s)

Comment: it isn't that simple. I'm attaching those bindings dynamically on elements that are also rendered dynamically ;-)

Comment: But that is exactly what event delegation is for... so yes it is that simple. See [Understanding event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: It is that simple.  You shouldn't try to "fix" duplicate bindings.  You should not duplicate bind in the first place.

Comment: I agree, @Taplar. But sometimes a hacky here and there might save some time of development.

Comment: @charlietfl, I'll take another look at it. tks

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit I got it working properly using

```
$('selector').off('.myNamespace').on('change.myNamespace', myFunction);
```

Doing this I don't end up unbinding any other event, I just unbind the one I really need.

PS.: I still don't know why `$('selector').off('change', myFunction)` doesn't work but I'll move forward.

Thanks.